# Problemas com Hibernate lazy

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Amigos, tudo bom?

Estou com um problema que é o famoso: **org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:**.

Eu sei que isto ocorre pelo fato de a sessão ter sido fechada e o hibernate não conseguir conectar para fazer os selects e etc, mas então, como conseguir os dados após a sessão estar fechada?

Por exemplo: Tenho essas classes:

**Estado**:

```
public class State  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_country")
private Country country;
private String description;
private String uf;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_timezone")
private TimeZone timeZone;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", targetEntity = City.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("description asc")
private Set<City> city;


    /get e set
}
```

**Cidade**:

```
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_state")
    private State state;
    private String description;

    //get e set
}
```

**Pessoa**:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private City city;

    /get e set
}
```

Se eu deixar em modo EAGER a lista de cidades na entidade state e toda vez pegar uma pessoa nova ela vai acabar fazendo vários selects pegando todas as cidades daquele estado. Porém, se eu deixar em modo LAZY e precisas acessar minha lista de cidade eu recebo a excessão ** org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException** devido a conexão estar fechada.

**Como contornar este problema?** Alguem da uma mão?

Comment: Sugiro manter a lista de cidades como *lazy load* e forçar o carregamento delas no repositório do estado. Assim, qualquer entidade que tiver um relacionamento para o estado não vai carregar a lista de cidades. Quando o aplicativo estiver interessado na lista de cidades ele certamente estará carregando o estado a partir do repositório de estados e não a partir de um relacionamento - e nessa hora a lista de cidades estará carregada.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão

Comment: É preciso termos mais detalhes para entender o seu problema. Por exemplo, qual a parte do seu código abre e fecha a sessão do Hibernate? Ou você está usando algum framework (Sprign, EJB, etc) para gerenciar a sessão? Se sim, como está configurado? Onde a chamada que dá no LazyInitializationException ocorre em seu código? Enfim, são muitos detalhes que precisamos conhecer para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Answer (score 2):

Olá. O problema é o modo como o hibernate vai tratar os relacionamento entre suas classes. Você utilizou o atributo **fetch = FetchType.LAZY**. Com isso ele não "pega magicamente" a lista de cidades relacionadas e em algum momento sua aplicação está fazendo algo como... State.getCity(). Existem pelo menos duas forma de resolver isso.

1 - Você precisa preencher essa lista antes de utiliza-la. Tente Implementar algum método como... public List getCitiesByState(State s){};

2 - Você pode alterar o modo como o hibernate trata esse relacionamento alterando o atributo **fetch = FetchType.LAZY** para **fetch = FetchType.EAGER**

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como está fazendo a sua consulta, mas utilize `JOIN FETCH` nela, assim o Hibernate vai inicializar os objetos que estão mapeados como `lazy`.

Exemplo HQL:

```
SELECT s FROM State s JOIN FETCH s.city c;
```